# Python get all Unique Pair combinations from list of elements

Tags: python

I tried to get the all unique pair combinations from a list.

Here is what I have done so far,

```
import itertools

# Unique Combination Pairs for list of elements
def uniqueCombinations(list_elements):
    l = list(itertools.combinations(list_elements, 2))
    s = set(l)
    # print('actual', len(l), l)
    return list(s)
```

**Test Case**

```
sample = ["apple", "orange", "banana", "grapes", "mango"]
uniqueCombinations(sample)
```

**Output**

```
[('apple', 'banana'),
 ('orange', 'mango'),
 ('orange', 'grapes'),
 ('apple', 'grapes'),
 ('orange', 'banana'),
 ('apple', 'mango'),
 ('grapes', 'mango'),
 ('apple', 'orange'),
 ('banana', 'mango'),
 ('banana', 'grapes')]
```

**The input will be unique strings of list**. Assume that duplicate elements will not be passed.

Is there a better / more elegant / more accurate way to do this??

Comment: `uniqueCombinations(['apple', 'orange', 'apple'])` returns `[('orange', 'apple'), ('apple', 'apple'), ('apple', 'orange')]`. Is this the output you are expecting for this case?

Comment: yes, the original `list_elements` can contains duplicates.

Comment: When I run your code it does not produce that output.

Comment: The code in the question or in the answer??

Comment: Is the order of the tuple important? If you sort `list_elements` you get `('banana', 'orange')` but lose `('orange', 'banana')`. The challenge is poorly defined. If so why are you duplicating output with `['apple', 'orange', 'apple']`?

Comment: Assume that the list of elements is the column names of a dataframe. I'm trying to plot column vs column using matplotlib. I want unique pairs to plot that. Ex: 'apple' vs 'banana' or 'banana' vs 'apple' it gives me the same or similar results which I don't need. Here I want only unique pairs to get my work done

Comment: I specifically need unique pairs from the list of elements, either as a list of lists or list of tuples or in any other way... in an efficient, accurate, and faster form

Comment: @Pluviophile Double-checking here, so in your Test Case 2 where the function returns `[('apple', 'orange'), ('apple', 'apple'), ('orange', 'apple')]`, isn't this a bad result for your use case? Since it would give you both `('apple', 'orange')` and `('orange', 'apple')`, and it sounds like you actually only want one of these, not both. This comment is in response to `Ex: 'apple' vs 'banana' or 'banana' vs 'apple' it gives me the same or similar results which I don't need.`

Comment: Well, I don't pass the duplicate strings as input. I think I need to update this...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations), emphasis mine:

> Return r length subsequences of elements from the input iterable.
>
> The combination tuples are emitted in lexicographic ordering according to the order of the input iterable. So, if the input iterable is sorted, the combination tuples will be produced in sorted order.
>
> Elements are treated as unique based on their position, not on their value. **So if the input elements are unique, there will be no repeat values in each combination.**

Which means as long as we pass in a collection of unique elements to `itertools.combinations`, there will be no duplicate values in the combinations it returns. And if we can assume that the input list will not contain any duplicate elements, we can rewrite the function like so:

```python
import itertools

def unique_combinations(elements: list[str]) -> list[tuple[str, str]]:
    """
    Precondition: `elements` does not contain duplicates.
    Postcondition: Returns unique combinations of length 2 from `elements`.

    >>> unique_combinations(["apple", "orange", "banana"])
    [("apple", "orange"), ("apple", "banana"), ("orange", "banana")]
    """
    return list(itertools.combinations(elements, 2))
```

Comment: @superbrain True, then in that case we'd need clarification from @Pluviophile on what assumptions can be made about `list_elements`.

Comment: Trying the above code, I'm getting `TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: Is that becoz of this part `: list[str] -> list[tuple[str, str]]`??

Comment: @Pluviophile sounds like you're not running Python 3.9, you can either omit those type hints or use `from typing import List, Tuple` -> `List[str]` `List[Tuple[str, str]]`

Comment: Yes, I'm not using 3.9+, using 3.7. Thank you for the Fix

Comment: @superbrain I think the output for `['apple', 'orange', 'apple']` is actually a bug not a feature, with the OP's code. [Check here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/256952#comment507445_256952), what do you think?

Comment: Sounds like I can revert back to my original answer then, admittedly I should have asked for more clarification in the beginning to clarify the problem statement.

Comment: @Peilonrayz Well, initially the OP's usage of `set` suggested the input *can* have duplicates (they wouldn't do that otherwise), then they edited the question to make it *clear* that it can have duplicates, then they edited it *again* to *rule them out*. So I guess this answer is fine until the next question edit :-)

Comment: @superbrain Yeah been quite the roller-coaster ;)